What is the correct way of debugging which installed app is causing Windows Explorer and Desktop to refresh frequently?
Windows 10 Single language, 22h2, 64-bit, build 19045.4598 (up to date), i7-11800H.
For some reason I can't pinpoint yet, Windows Explorer and Desktop are constantly refreshing. On Windows Explorer, it even resets windows scroll position. On Desktop, icons flash and I don't even have time to rename a file/folder, sometimes.
SFC, chkdsk and DISM didn't make a difference, as well as rebooting.
It wasn't always like that so I blame a program I may have installed. I removed everything that's superfluous and I still get the mad refreshing. There are a huge number of possibilities, though, and I believe there must be a saner way of debugging it.
What should I do?

I would start by booting into Safe Mode to determine if an application is installed on the system, causing File Explorer to crash or refresh.  If it does not happen in Safe Mode, I would use AutoRuns and, through a process of elimination, determine which application is causing the problem.  I would then [edit] your question so we can help resolve the incompatibility problem itself.


Have you installed any cloud storage, such as DropBox, OneDrive or Google Drive, that would periodically check folders? If so, test disabling the service, or at least turn off storing Desktop.

Look at Task Manager, Details tab, for any process that you might have installed. Leave Task Manager running, and if you're lucky, you might spot a small jump in CPU usage for a process when that refresh occurs.

Use Sysinternals Autoruns to see what starts by itself. In particular, look at Logon, Explorer and Scheduled Tasks for a likely culprit.

Check what you've installed in Programs and Features, and consider if any would be a likely cause.

Do a malware scan -- poorly-implemented screen-scraping might behave the way you describe.


